# Set Shadow on Bottom UIView only

Tags: ios, uiview, shadow

I want to create bottom only shadow on UIView. Right now with this function, will create shadow in top, bottom, left, and right.

```
func setCardView(view : UIView){
    view.layer.masksToBounds = false
    view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    view.layer.shadowRadius = 2
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
}
```

Is there anyway to only create shadow in the bottom?
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 79):

I think the proper way of thinking of shadow is, the shadow belongs to the object, which is the button, the uiview, not just part of the side. Imagining there is a virtual light source. You can't really just create a shadow for one side.

With that being said, the shadow will always be the shadow of the view as a whole. However, you can change the shadow offset to make it towards to the bottom.

```
view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
```

This means you want the light source shoot the light from top to make the shadow to the bottom. The reason you still see some shadow at the top is the shadow radius. which is to simulate the `diffuse` of the light. The more diffuse the light is, the softer the shadow will be so you will see top shadow still.

```
view.layer.shadowRadius = 1 or 0.5
```

try to reduce the radius also. it will give you a better visual result.

To understand umbra, penumbra and antumbra if you need, check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbra,_penumbra_and_antumbra

Comment: upvoting for the explanation.

Comment: yeah me too :-)

Comment: yeah me too, nice explanation

Comment: fabulous explanation almost cleared shadow concept.

Answer (score 25):

This adds a shadow only to bottom. Implemented as an extension to UIView

```
extension UIView {
func addBottomShadow() {
    layer.masksToBounds = false
    layer.shadowRadius = 4
    layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0 , height: 2)
    layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0,
                                                 y: bounds.maxY - layer.shadowRadius,
                                                 width: bounds.width,
                                                 height: layer.shadowRadius)).cgPath
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 20):

This code working for swift 4 and shadow applying for view Bottom:

```
view.layer.masksToBounds = false
view.layer.shadowRadius = 4
view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0 , height:2)
```

Comment: This code working for swift 4  and shadow applying for view  Bottom

Comment: Please, add this explanation in your answer, not in comment. Whoever will read the answer will understand better your code.

Answer (score 17):

If you really want a shadow only on one side of your `UIView`, you should set your `view.layer.shadowPath` to a `UIBezierPath`.

Here is an example which will only display a shadow at the bottom of the view:

```
view.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0,
                                                  y: bounds.maxY - layer.shadowRadius,
                                                  width: bounds.width,
                                                  height: layer.shadowRadius)).cgPath
```

Deconstructing the `CGRect` value, you get:

- `x` and `width` make sure the shadow takes the full horizontal width of your view (you might want to adjust them, for example using the `layer.shadowRadius` value as a basis for your offsetting)
- `y` and `height` make sure the shadow starts as low as possible and then is only as big as the radius

Of course, there are some cases where this won't work, for example when you want a `shadowRadius` larger than your view's `height`. In these cases, I would recommend using an image view or a masked layer.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 16):

Change your `shadowOffset`

```
 view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
```

Comment: it still give me a little shadow in top of that view

Comment: Can you try make the `height` value bigger?

Comment: Working fine when add the height 10 . Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Here's the proper way of applying shadow in Swift:

```
yourView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
yourView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6
yourView.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0
yourView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
```

Answer (score 7):

Old question but it seems none of the answers really answer the question.
While the above answers will work with a low `shadowRadius` you don't really get a 'shadow' effect.

You can absolutely add a shadow to just the bottom by using `UIBezierPath`

Heres how -

```
    let shadowWidth: CGFloat = 1.2 // Shadow width, will be the width furthest away from the view, this is equivalent to 120% of the views width
    let shadowHeight: CGFloat = 0.3 // Shadow height, again this is equivalent to 30%
    let shadowRadius: CGFloat = 5 
    let width = someView.frame.width
    let height = someView.frame.height // Get width and height of the view

    // Plot the path
    let shadowPath = UIBezierPath()
    shadowPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: shadowRadius / 2, y: height - shadowRadius / 2))
    shadowPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width - shadowRadius / 2, y: height - shadowRadius / 2))
    shadowPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width * shadowWidth, y: height + (height * shadowHeight)))
    shadowPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width * -(shadowWidth - 1), y: height + (height * shadowHeight)))
    // Add shadow
    someView.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath
    someView.layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
    someView.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
    someView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
```

This outputs this

[image]

Or if you wanted a simpler solution, with less options you could go with this

```
   let buttonHeight = someButton.frame.height
    let buttonWidth = someButton.frame.width

    let shadowSize: CGFloat = 15
    let contactRect = CGRect(x: -shadowSize, y: buttonHeight - (shadowSize * 0.2), width: buttonWidth + shadowSize * 2, height: shadowSize)
    someButton.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: contactRect).cgPath
    someButton.layer.shadowRadius = 5
    someButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6
```

Which will output this

[image]

Example here

https://github.com/hemo87/ExampleShadow/tree/master

Comment: Technically, this is creating a shadow on the shape you draw with `UIBezierPath` rather than the bottom of the UIView. It's purely drawing a new thing that has nothing to do with the original UIView. But that might just be what op wants to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

```
class ViewBottomShadow: UIView {
  init() {
    super.init(frame: .zero)
    backgroundColor = .white
    layer.masksToBounds = false
    layer.shadowRadius = 2
    layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0 , height:2)
  }

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just draw regular shadow and rotate it upside down, as simple as that

```
@objc func shadowView() -> UIView {
        let shadowView = UIView(frame: .zero)
        shadowView.backgroundColor = .white
        shadowView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.grey.cgColor
        shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
        shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        shadowView.layer.shadowRadius = 4
        shadowView.layer.compositingFilter = "multiplyBlendMode"
        return shadowView
    }

func idtm_addBottomShadow() {
        let shadow = shadowView()
        shadow.transform = transform.rotated(by: 180 * CGFloat(Double.pi))
        shadow.transform = transform.rotated(by: -1 * CGFloat(Double.pi))
        shadow.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(shadow)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            shadow.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            shadow.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            shadow.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            shadow.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1),
            ])
    }
```